# Saves As Macro throwing Run Time error '1004' despite working well in a different workbook

Tags: excel, vba, runtime, save-as

Thanks for all the help given here.

I am by no means a coder and spend hours searching forums and canabilising bits of code to create what I need. I built the below code to extract data from one workbook, based on the filter and then save as in a individual workbooks. This code worked really well for one workbook, but now I've tried to reuse it,it throws a 1004 runtime error when trying to save as. Any idea where it could be going wrong?

Many thanks,

Stephen

```
Sub Split()

Dim ws     As Worksheet
Dim wsNew  As Workbook
Dim rData  As Range
Dim rfl    As Range
Dim state  As String
Dim myValue As Variant
Dim sfilename As String
Dim FolderName As String
Dim strDir As String

myValue1 = InputBox("What date is this save for? (Format: DD Month)")

Range("B1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Combined Data")

With ws
Set rData = .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp))
.Columns(.Columns.Count).Clear
.Range(.Cells(2, 6), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=.Cells(1, .Columns.Count), Unique:=True

 MsgBox "Please select the folder to save files"
           FolderName = GetFolder()
        If FolderName = "" Then
        MsgBox "No folder was selected. Program will terminate."
        Exit Sub
    End If

For Each rfl In .Range(.Cells(2, .Columns.Count), .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).End(xlUp))
state = rfl.Text

strDir = FolderName & "\" & state

If Dir(strDir, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir strDir
Else

End If

Set wsNew = Workbooks.Add
sfilename = "Monday" & " " & myValue1 & " - Engagement" & ".xlsx"

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs strDir & "\" & sfilename
```

Comment: What is the date you are inputting?

Comment: @BigBen - 27 April (I'm avoiding special characters etc..)

Comment: `Debug.Print strDir & "\" & sfilename` - is it what you expect?

Comment: @BigBen, Thanks very helpful. Turns out there was an errant space at the end of the data from the filter. The problem is this data is drawn from an SQL query from a a central database. This errant space may exist in other bits of data. Is there a bit of code I can add to remove any spaces at the end of the"state" variable?

Comment: `Trim` probably.

Comment: @BigBen, Great thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out the actual reason for this common error code - 1004. Edit your function/VBA code and run your program in debug mode to identify the line which is causing it. And then, add below piece of code to see the error,

```
On Error Resume Next
// your code goes here which causes 1004 error
If Err.Number > 0 Then
  Debug.Print Err.Number & ":" & Err.Description
End If
```

I'd suggest using debug shortcut keys on your keyboard - Step Into (<kbd>F8</kbd>), Step Over (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd>), Step Out (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd>)